# Partition of tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have read that in a case where a table has many columns, but most of the time only one of them is used (say a title column in a forum post), a way to increase performance would be a partition to two tables, where one will contain only the title and the other one will contain the other columns (such as the forum post body).

However, in case I use

```
select ForumTitle from Forum;
```

won't that be good enough to prevent the load of all columns (such as the forum post's body) to the memory, and eliminate the need of partition?

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The idea of partitioning the table is that the resulting table is much smaller; it fits on fewer pages. Therefore if MySQL needs to access the data freqeuently the chances that requested data containting the ForumTitles are already in memory are much bigger.

If a table contains a lot of fields, much more pages need to be cached in memory to cache the same amount of ForumTitles.

MySQL stores all columns of a row sequentially on a page and cannot load nor cache only part of a row.